# Faced issue: "Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to show name of income and name of expenses in IncomeExpense table which is connected to both income and expenses tables and both of these tables have name column from which to get information and show it in IncomeExpense table. I have properly connected all of the tables but get error: "Trying to get property 'title' of non-object 
View:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<br>
<br>
    <div class="card bg-muted">
    <h1>{{$incexp->IncomeExpense}}</h1>
    <small>{{$incexp->created_at}}</small>
    <small> {{$incexp->income->title }}</small>**--get issue here**
    <small>{{$incexp->SumOfMoney}}</small>
    <small> {{$incexp->Comments}}</small>
    <small> {{$incexp->expense->title}}</small>**--get issue here**
    <small>Кем создан: <strong>{{$incexp->user->name}}</strong></small>

    </div>
    <br>
<a href="/incexp/{{$incexp->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>

{!! Form::open(['action'=>['IncomeExpenseController@destroy', $incexp->id], 'method' =>'POST', 'class'=>'float-right']) !!}
    {{Form::hidden('_method', 'Delete')}}
    {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

IncomeExpense model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class IncomeExpenses extends Model
{

    public function income(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Income');
    }
    public function expense(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Expenses');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

Income model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Income extends Model
{
    public function incomeExpense(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\IncomeExpenses');
    }
}
```

Expense model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Expenses extends Model
{

    public function incomeExpense(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\IncomeExpenses');
    }
}
```

Comment: Put some debugs in, it's telling you expense is not an object, find out what it is and work back through the code with debugs until you find out where it went wrong.  eg:

echo '<pre>'.print_r( $incexp,true).'</pre>';

Comment: Can you `var_dump($incexp->income); die;` and post the return debug value.
Maybe the `$incexp->income)` is returning an array and not an object and you should access it this way `$incexp->income['title'];`